# What is this symbol, and it belong to which-system or convensions?

Tags: antenna, transmission-line, symbol

[image: Common textbook symbol antenna]

This is a very common- symbol used in school-textbooks as a symbol for **antenna.**

This website (http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/figure-shows-arrangement-generating-traveling-electromagnetic-wave-shortwave-radio-region--q1017746) mentioned this as the symbol of [Transmission line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line).

[image] (http://s3.amazonaws.com/answer-board-image/8700a5dc-2c5e-473c-89d3-2a6dde823364.gif).

However, I did-not found any information about this symbol in google and wikipedia. As well, outside school-textbooks I yet not seen this symbol in any professional circuit diagram. What is this symbol? and in which sign-convention it is/was used?

Comment: You mean the dipole antenna symbol? http://www.electronic-symbols.com/electric-electronic-symbols/antenna-aerial-symbols.htm or the twisted pair that stands for a transmission line?

Comment: I meant the symbol looking like a twisted pair. i.e. horizontal, DNA-like symbol. i.e. the first-one. And in second image the horizontal, DNA-shaped symbol

Comment: It written right under it: transmission line. When they are generic, sometimes people represent them with coaxial cables, sometimes with twisted pairs. No biggie. Try googling "twisted pair symbol" and look at the pictures

Comment: that's a twisted pair.

Comment: thanks. Somehow I knew it wrongly. The symbol, mostly used in the chapter of discovery of generating electromagnetic wave by Hertz. But in these diagrams, since that is not separately pointed than antenna, I knew this symbol as antenna.

Comment: Wikipedia says, twisted-pair was invented by Alexander Graham Bell , so it is an **old invention**, so not impossible to use it in old experiments.

Comment: @SredniVashtar That means not necessarily twisted-pair, it may be any other type of signal-carrying wire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This symbol is the common way to draw a **twisted pair**.

Note that this is common, in literature, and very intuitive, but **this isn't the standard way**.

This is a twisted pair in standards:

[image]

And this is antenna:

[image]